# Combinations - teachers taking classes

Tags: combinations

I posted recently trying to work out how many combinations were possible for my scheduling algorithm of teachers to classes. So if I had 4 classes and 3 teachers 
The combinations would be 4^3 right? 
I forgot to mention that not all classes need to be filled. 
So if I had 1 teacher and 3 classes the possibilities would be.
The one teacher takes these classes "takes none" -1 - 2 - 3 - 1,2 - 1,3- 1,2,3 -2,3 
So there are 8 possibilities for one teacher and 3 classes

What would be the maths for this on a larger scale, such as 50 classes, ten teachers 
Thankyou

Comment: Is it the case that every teacher teaches 1 class (some don't get taught) or that every class gets 1 teacher (some teachers get more than one class)?

Comment: some will not get taught.

Comment: no lessons take place // lesson 1 takes place, 2 and 3 canceled // lesson 2 takes place 1 and 3 cancelled and so on

Comment: So do you have the condition that: each of $n$ classes can be assigned at most one of $m$ teachers, but each teacher can teach multiple classes?

Comment: a teacher can teach as many classes. so all 3 //
each class only has one teacher

Answer (score 0):

So, each of $n$ classes can be assigned at most one of $m$ teachers, but each teacher can teach multiple classes.

Thus there is choice of one of $m+1$ options, made $n$ times, with repetition allowed.

The count of distinct ways to do this is: $(m+1)^n$

---

EG: With one teacher and three classes we have $(1+1)^3=8$ ways.

With ten teachers, and fifty classes, we have $11^{50}$

Comment: Great thank you

didnt realise how big my search area was going to be for this scheduling algorithm